# Kafka- SAS Viya connection

Tags: apache-kafka, sas

I have no experience working on Kafka and I am new to SAS Viya.
Can Kafka data be pulled into SAS Viya? Either by -

1. Direct import using any connector?
2. Importing Real Time data from Kafka somewhere and import into SAS Viya from there.

Comment: Have you tried searching SAS pages? https://www.sas.com/en_us/software/event-stream-processing/features-list.html#c2287af2-a85e-49cc-9df4-8a883b24afd0

Comment: Hello, Yes I did. No clarity for SAS Viya -Kafka connection as such. I am looking specifically for SAS Viya. Thanks

Comment: Isn't KAFKA just a way to mange moving data? Why not just connect Viya to the place where KAFKA put the data?

Comment: @Tom Kafka stores data itself. It needs clients to connect with it